# undefined is not a function while testing ReactJS using Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mocha.js

I am trying to test a simple page having form with 2 input fields using `ReactJs` and `Mocha`.

When I run the test I am getting the error:

```
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at module.exports (/Users/johnp/Documents/myapp/work/projects/myapp-etd-portal/test/setup.js:5:35)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/johnp/Documents/myapp/work/projects/myapp-etd-portal/test/component/NameTest.js:1:28)
        at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
        at normalLoader (/Users/johnp/Documents/myapp/work/projects/myapp-etd-portal/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:160:5)
        at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/johnp/Documents/myapp/work/projects/myapp-etd-portal/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:173:7)
        at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
        at require (module.js:384:17)
        at /Users/johnp/Documents/myapp/work/projects/myapp-etd-portal/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:192:27
```

Below are my code files:

1.setup.js: basic set-up file

```
module.exports = function(markup) {
    if (typeof document !== 'undefined') return
    var jsdom          = require("jsdom").jsdom
    global.document    = jsdom(markup || '')
    global.window      = document.createWindow()

    var chai = require('chai');
    chai.config.includeStack = true;
    global.expect = chai.expect;
}
```

NameTest.js: actual test page.

```
    NameTest.js
    require('../../test/setup')('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>')
    var React          = require('react')
    var ReactAddons    = require('react/addons')
    var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils

describe('Name page component', function(){
    before('render element', function() {

        try {
            var renderedComponent = TestUtils.renderToString(
                <InputFieldItem />
            );
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    });

    it('First & Last <input> fields should be of type "text"', function() {
        this.formElement = React.findDOMNode(TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(renderedComponent, 'form'))
        this.firstNameElement = React.findDOMNode(TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(renderedComponent, 'input')[0])
        this.lastNameElement = React.findDOMNode(TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(renderedComponent, 'input')[1])

    });
});
```

I have my gulp task set up and I run the test using: gulp bundle && npm run test.
It has been very frustrating to look for a solution and appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the stack trace shows, `undefined is not a function` at `setup.js:5:35` (line 5, column 35).

```
global.document    = jsdom(markup || '')
global.window      = document.createWindow() // <-- refers to this
```

Assigning something to node's `global` object by doing `global.document = ...`, is not the same as creating a `document` variable in the global scope. To access something on node's global object you will always access it as a property, so do this:

```
global.window = global.document.createWindow();
```

Comment: Changed as suggested but still getting the same error at the line:  global.window = global.document.createWindow();

Answer (score 0):

Switch `document.createWindow()` for `document.defaultView` as per the [docs](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#for-the-hardcore-jsdomjsdom) and it'll work.